# UItableView with multiple images and setting onclick on each one of them

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a scenario where I want to keep "thumbnails" of images on the row of the tableview. I decide on runtime the numbers of images that goes in a row.

Secondly, On click of any of the image I want to launch a viewcontroller with elaborated image of it with some description.

How can I achieve this?

```
|________________|
| 1 2 3  4  5  6 |
|________________|
| 7 8 9 10 11 12 |
|________________|
| 12 14 15       |
|________________|
```

Imagine the numbers above as thumbnails. Onclick of any of the number I want to launch a new view controller which gives details about the image.

code snippet:

```
-(void) populateTableView
{

    NSMutableArray* srcArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[ImageDataSource sharedImageDataSource] getThumbnailsSrcArray]];

    int noOfImages = srcArray.count;

    float rowc = (noOfImages / ROW_ELEM_COUNT) + 0.5;

    int rowCount = roundf(rowc);

    titleData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    int j=0;
    for (int i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {

        NSMutableArray* rowArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int k=0; k < ROW_ELEM_COUNT; k++) {

            if (j < noOfImages) {
                NSString* imgPath = [srcArray objectAtIndex:j];
                UIImage* img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];
                [rowArray addObject:img];
                [img release];
                imgPath=nil;
            }
            j++;
        }
        [titleData addObject:rowArray]; 
    }

    titleView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90.0,156.0,590.0,630.0) 
                                             style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    titleView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:titleView];
    [titleView release];

}
```

So basically I have array of array as my DS. index of each array will be row of table view and the array inside will have images. But I am not sure how to populate the tableview.
Any clue anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices.

• Add a UIButton with the UIImage and add each button as a subview on your tableview cell.

or

• Figure out where on the cell the user tapped and from here calculate which image they tapped and which action to take:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    // do your stuff
    //..
}
```

Comment: Do I have to subclass UITableViewCell or not? The content type is only image(or uibutton) so It should be fine if we create them in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Yeah you can easily add subviews to `cell.contentView` in this method.